# drop down list with more then one dilimiter. can get JS to work

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style

Ok so i am trying to get a textarea where a user can type in text. select a delimiter from a dropdown list. Hit count and it will count how many times it splits.

I cant seem to get my code to split at all. here is my code.

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function()  { 
document.getElementById("change").onclick = function() {



var paragraph = document.getElementById('box').value;
var x = document.getElementById("changeCase");
var getInfo = document.getElementById('ParaWrite');
var LowerCase = " ";
var splitAT = " ";
alert("above the for loop"); 

if (x.checked === true)
{
LowerCase = paragraph.toLowerCase();
}
else
{
LowerCase = paragraph;
}

for (var i = 0; i <document.form1.split.options.length; i++)
{
if (document.form1.split.options[i].selected === true)
    {
    splitAT = paragraph.split(options[i]);
    }
}
document.write(splitAT);
```

doc write is just so i can see if it even makes it that far in the code and it does not.

here is my HTML

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">

<textarea type="text" id="box" value=""/></textarea>
<input type='checkbox' name='write' id='changeCase' value='Check'/><br>

<input  type='button' value="Count" id="change"/>
<select name="split" id="split">
        <option value="like">like</option>
        <option value="monkey">monkey</option>
        <option value="I">I</option>
        <option value=".">.</option>
        <option value=",">,</option>
        <option value="?">?</option>
        <option value=" ">[Space]</option>
    </select>    
</form>
<div id="ParaWrite">
</div>
```

Comment: keep it mind that i am not using all my var's so its more of a work in progress. but i keep getting an error on line 26 of JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` is not defined.

```
splitAT = paragraph.split(document.form1.split.options[i]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/KeZEd/

Comment: tried it and still gives me an error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on my code... worked with JSfiddle and that might work. let me plug and chug it out real quick.

Comment: @user2041757 on which line?

Comment: line 26. if i copy the code and run it. i do not get that error.

Comment: @user2041757 so you're saying that the problem is fixed?